# VB Net - LINQ query into a datatable

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I need to pass the LINQ results (`currentDetailRow`)I am looping into an datatable. I can only seem to do it by passing the LINQ result values individually and not `currentDetailRow` as a whole due to it being a different type. This should be simple and common and I've looked around and can only find even more complicated solutions than just passing each value. But this would be maintenance pain having to add a new column at many different places through the code.

```
Dim detailQuery = From detailCursor In dtCsvData
                  Select OrderNo = detailCursor.Field(Of Integer)("OrderNo"),
                         LineNo = detailCursor.Field(Of Integer)("LineNo"),
                         Style = detailCursor.Field(Of String)("Style"),
                         SizeDesc = detailCursor.Field(Of String)("SizeDesc"),
                         Colourway = detailCursor.Field(Of String)("Colourway"),
                         Quantity = detailCursor.Field(Of Integer)("Quantity")
                  Where OrderNo = currentOrderLine.OrderNo
                  Where LineNo = currentOrderLine.LineNo
                  Where Style = currentOrderLine.Style

For Each currentDetailRow In detailQuery

    dtPLMOrderDetailData.Rows.Add(currentDetailRow.OrderNo,
                                  currentDetailRow.LineNo,
                                  currentDetailRow.SizeDesc,
                                  currentDetailRow.Colourway,
                                  currentDetailRow.Quantity)

   ' But want something like this!
   ' dtPLMOrderDetailData.Rows.Add(currentDetailRow)

Next
```

Comment: We dont know anything about the columns of `dtPLMOrderDetailData` and `dtCsvData`. Do they have the same columns?

Comment: This is why [Object-relational mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) has been invented. Use Entity Framework (EF6) or EF-Core.

Comment: `dtPLMOrderDetailData` is a datatable with some of the same columns as `dtCsvData` datatable. So I am querying those specific columns in a datatable with LINQ and putting in another.

Comment: `dtCsvData` I loaded from a CSV. Personally as a SQL writer I didn't like LINQ at all so if there is a better way to select some results from one datatable into another I'm interested. I've seen other ways bu  a lot more code so doesn't make sense to use. Note, I'm recently self taught .Net so anything except code examples is gibberish to me.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I'll add this Entity Framework to my to learn list. Looks like a lot to learn just to simplify the above code but possibly useful long term to understand. Thanks.